# How to avoid horizontal scrolling in "systemctl status"?

Tags: systemd, output

In a long line in `systemctl status` it's necessary to scroll horizontally which makes it quite hard to copy the output. Is there a way to get linebreaks at the end of terminal (like `nano -$` would do)?

I'm not looking for a workaround like redirecting the output into a temporary file and displaying it with an editor which supports the output.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use the `--no-pager` option in conjunction with the `--full` option, which will force the lines to wrap:

```bsh
systemctl status --no-pager --full
```

[image]

If you want to preserve the paging functionality, you can just pipe the output of `systemctl status` to `less` / `more` directly, since connecting the command's STDOUT to a pipe will force the command to print a raw output:

```bsh
systemctl status | less
```

Comment: I wonder why you didn't have to add `--full` to the the long line in the process tree broken. I have to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @KarlRichter Sorry, failures all around tonight. I actually *had* to add `--full`, but outputting to a pipe (`head`) took out the need for that, and at some point I ended up thinking it just wouldn't have been useful when used in conjunction with `--no-pager`. You actually need `--full`.

Comment: Is there anyway to *change* the pager to LESS?

Comment: yes, you van use the PAGER or the SYSTEMD_PAGER environment variables to set the pager. If you put an empty string into the environment variable then you can switch this, err, feature off. Moreover, see
the SYSTEMD_LESS environment variable.