# How do I exit the systemctl status command's output?

Tags: command-line, systemd, pager

How does one go about getting the command line prompt back after using the systemctl status command? The command appears to succeed as it displays the status information of the requested service. However, the terminal appears to lock up after using the command.

Comment: You can use the `--no-pager` option - see related [How to avoid horizontal scrolling in “systemctl status”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747156/how-to-avoid-horizontal-scrolling-in-systemctl-status)

Comment: @DavidFoerster as I noted in the other q, that doesn't actually use a pager, only the appearance of one.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you mean

```
systemctl status
```

at the end it shows this:

```
      ├─systemd-journald.service
         │ └─318 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
         ├─fwupd.service
         │ └─1703 /usr/lib/fwupd/fwupd
         ├─systemd-networkd.service
         │ └─395 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
         └─cups-browsed.service
           └─2918 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
lines 172-194/194 (END)
```

... then press a `q` for quit.

---

As steeldriver noted in comments: use `--no-pager` if you do not want this behaviour [see details](https://askubuntu.com/a/747158/22308).

```
systemctl status --no-pager
```

Comment: I wonder why would they not show this by default like nano does.

Comment: Sweet. I used this in a script to give feedback during an install and without your fix it forces you to crtl C out of it.  Thanks!

Comment: `--no-pager` also works great for noninteractive scripts

Comment: Can we also do `systemctl status package | cat`?

Comment: what is the reason for systemctl status  to behave that way ?

Answer (score 11):

Check what `systemctl` is running in another terminal:

```
$ pstree -pa $(pgrep systemctl)
systemctl,2100 status
  └─less,2101
```

And from [`man less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/less.1):

```
q or Q or :q or :Q or ZZ
  Exits less.
```

Answer (score 5):

`systemctl status | cat` does the job as well. You're just redirecting the output of `systemctl status` to `cat` which in turn dumps everything on the console without any pagination

Comment: Unfortunately this way the `systemctl` exit status is lost (unless `set -o pipefail`).